# Suburban air bag light

Tags: supplemental-restraint-system, suburban, recall

I have a 2005 Suburban and the air bag light for passenger side says on. Does anyone know if that was on recall list?

Comment: You're suggesting the light stays on whether someone is sitting in the seat or not?

Comment: Your vehicle has 8 recalls and none are related to the air bag.   https://www.nhtsa.gov/vehicle/2005/CHEVROLET/SUBURBAN/4%252520DR#recalls

Answer (score 1):

All recalls are available online. For modern cars the airbag is not ON when the seat is vacant so in case of an accident the bag is not actuated. The car manual explains this. If someone sits and the light stays ON, please see a certified mechanic.Airbags have sensors to detect a specific weight. There is a list as to detecting an issue that keeps the light ON. I recommend only professional assistance. Cheers.